# automatically quit less after a short time

Tags: less

I use less to view the text output of a command that has sensitive information.  Less is good for this as it uses an alternate screen and wipes it after use.  I'd like the less session to quit after a short time, like say 5 minutes.

Is there any simple command line way to invoke less with piped text and have it quit automatically after say 5 minutes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you have GNU coreutils, a somewhat simple approach is to replace `less` with `timeout --foreground 600 less; printf '\033[?47h'; clear; printf '\033[?1049l'; stty cooked echo` in such sensitive commands. The `timeout` command kills a process after a given duration, the `--foreground` switch allows `less` to use the TTY, and `stty cooked echo` fixes the terminal after killing `less`.  In case killing `less` prevented the clear and exit of the alternate screen, the intervening commands do that.

The escape sequences used in the `printf` commands are appropriate for a DEC-compatible terminal (emulator) such as Xterm. Your specific terminal may use different sequences to accomplish this task.

A simple function:

```
tless () {
  timeout --foreground 600 less "$@"
  printf '\033[?47h' # Enter alternate screen
  clear
  printf '\033[?1049l' # Exit alternate screen and restore cursor
  </dev/tty stty cooked echo # Use in a pipe requires specifying the TTY
}
```

can make for substantially less typing.

---

Thanks @meuh for pointing out that the original version might not clear or exit the alternate screen.

Edited to allow `tless some-file`.  Further, this version has been tested on Linux and Solaris 11.

Comment: Killing `less` may leave the terminal in the alternate screen, showing the data. You would probably want to add a `clear`, and then a command to return from the alt screen, which for `xterm` is `printf "\e[?47l"`

Comment: If you have `ncurses` installed, you should have a `reset` command which will do a “soft reset” of the terminal (which normally clears the screen and drops out of alternate view). It also does roughly the same as `stty sane`.

Comment: You might be able to use the exit status to avoid the `reset` on normal (non-timeout, non-error) exit.

Comment: @WillCrawford Finally got around to testing this (and made some edits).  Running `< somefile timeout 1 less || reset` did not clear the alternate screen, but did erase the normal screen. `stty sane` sets the wrong erase character on my system though, so I still need to fix that ...

Comment: Thanks.  I had to adjust it a bit to make it work on BSD and MacOS as well as linux but it works.  
  tless () {
    timeout 5s less "$@";
    printf '\033[?47h' # Enter alternate screen; 
    clear;
    printf '\033[?1049l' # Exit alternate screen and restore cursor;
    stty -f /dev/tty cooked echo # Use in a pipe requires specifying the TTY;
  }

Comment: @k-h I didn't realize `-F` was non-portable.  Shows how much I use `stty`.  I just updated to a version that works on both the machines I'm currently using